# compare dataframes columns in R

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes. Both of them have the same columns names, but the first one has more variables than the second one. I want to know which columns match on both DFs or which columns are in the first DF that are not in the second one

Comment: You might want to check out: http://stat545.com/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html the dplyr package's join functions are quite useful for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to SO!

You can modify this code to help answer your question. Check out `?setdiff` for more information on that command.

```
vars1 <- colnames(dataframe1)
vars2 <- colnames(dataframe2)

setdiff(vars1, vars2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to find out the unique part of `colnames(df1)` and `colnames(df2)`，maybe you can try `gplots::venn`

```
library(gplots)
t1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
t2 <- c("a", "b" ,"d")  # assume t1 and t2 is your column name of df1 and df2
test <- venn(list(t1,t2))

test
```

you got:

[image]